# why do i have 2 OLAP cubes when i only expect one?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, tfs

we have sharepoint installed on a server "SP1" we have TFS installed on a server "TFS2". we hooked the sharepoint server up to TFS and hooked it up to a subsite to my mainsite in my only site collection. now we see 2 olap cubes - one in TFS2 (the one that has good data), and one in SP1.

why would there be 2 olap cubes created in this event? i know the 'right one' to use is TFS2 but the SP1 confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysis Services was running on Sharepoint and it was also running on TFS server. Since we don't use Sharepoint for TFS analysis services we stopped the service and the cube disappeared.